# Wildcard expression comparison not working

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, comparison, sh

I need to compare if the 2nd line of the input file contains the string `premium-world-check.xsd`. If it is present, I need not do anything.
If it is not present, I need to prepend to another file.

I have below input file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<records xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="premium-world-check.xsd">
<record category="INDIVIDUAL">
<tag1>
<tag2>
....
</tag2>
</tag1>
```

Below is my code,

```
xsdFlag=`sed -n '2p' ${myInputFile}`
if [ $xsdFlag == *"premium-world-check.xsd"* ]
then
    echo "Prepending not required"
else
    echo "<records xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="premium-world-check.xsd">" | cat - ${myInputFile} > wcTemp.xml && mv wcTemp.xml ${myInputFile}
    echo "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>" | cat - ${myInputFile} > wcTemp.xml && mv wcTemp.xml ${myInputFile}
    echo "PREPENDING:"
fi
```

I am getting unknown operator in my `if` condition.

Comment: Try [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net). It points out that "[ .. ] [can't match globs](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2081). Use [[ .. ]] or grep."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this; I've made a couple of fixes.

```
xsdFlag=`sed -n '2p' "$myInputFile"`

if [[ "$xsdFlag" == *"premium-world-check.xsd"* ]]; then
    echo "Prepending not required"
else
    echo '<records xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="premium-world-check.xsd">' | cat - "$myInputFile" > wcTemp.xml && mv wcTemp.xml "$myInputFile"
    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' | cat - "$myInputFile" > wcTemp.xml && mv wcTemp.xml "$myInputFile"
    echo "PREPENDING:"
fi
```

One problem was using standard POSIX `[ ... ]` instead of Bash `[[ ... ]]`, which you need to use wildcards.

The other problem was that you weren't escaping your quotation marks in your XML string. I changed the outer quotes from double quotes to single quotes to fix this.

You also weren't quoting your filenames, which is needed to prevent errors when they contain spaces.

Comment: your fix works as I was expecting. Thanks for the other fixes also !

Comment: No problem, glad to help! :)

Comment: Quoting paremeter expansions inside `[[ ... ]]` isn't strictly necessary, but it doesn't hurt.